# Doctrine entity always saves null on persist even when set

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to persist some data to the database but even though I'm setting a field it sets it to null when the actual SQL runs.  The field is set to not null in the database which throws an error.

My code:

```
$db_order = new Orders;

$db_order->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
$db_order->setLastUpdated(null);
$db_order->setDateAssigned(null);
$db_order->setCreatedBy($user->getId());

$db_order->setAttachmentId($order->getFaxId());
$db_order->setPatientId($order->getPatientId());
$db_order->setPaymentType($order->getPaymentType());
$db_order->setInsuranceName($order->getInsuranceName());
$db_order->setInsuranceNo($order->getInsuranceNo());
$db_order->setCash($order->getCash());
$db_order->setPrimaryClientId($order->getPrimaryClient());
$db_order->setSecondaryClients($secondaryClients);
$db_order->setEmployees($employees);
$db_order->setDates($dates);
$db_order->setNotes($note);


dump($db_order->getPatientId());

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($db_order);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I was double checking with that dump before the persist and it has the field set correctly.  Yet when the page runs...

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'patient_id' cannot be null

I don't understand how it could be null? Any ideas?

### Orders Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\GroupSequenceProviderInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrdersRepository")
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider()
 */
class Orders implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface
{
    const TYPE_InsuranceOnly = 1;
    const TYPE_InsuranceAndCash = 2;
    const TYPE_CashOnly = 3;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Patients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $patients;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="primary_client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $primaryClient;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getPatients(): Patients
    {
        return $this->patients;
    }

    public function getPrimaryClient(): Clients
    {
        return $this->primaryClient;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date_created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $last_updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_assigned;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $created_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Attachments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $attachment_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $patient_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","cashOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance And Collect or Cash Only then Cash field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $payment_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","insuranceOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance Only or Insurance And Collect then Insurance Name field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $insurance_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","insuranceOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance Only or Insurance And Collect then Insurance # field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $insurance_no;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=15, scale=2, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","cashOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance And Collect or Cash Only then Cash field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $cash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="primary_client_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $primaryClientId;

    /**
     * One Order has Many Secondary Clients.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Clients")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="orders_secondary_clients",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $secondaryClients;

    /**
     * One Order has Many Employees.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="orders_employees",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      )
     */
    private $employees;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDates", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $dates;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=100000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $status = 0;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateAssigned(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_assigned;
    }

    public function setDateAssigned(?\DateTimeInterface $date_assigned): self
    {
        $this->date_assigned = $date_assigned;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy(): ?int
    {
        return $this->created_by;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy(int $created_by): self
    {
        $this->created_by = $created_by;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_created;
    }

    public function setDateCreated(\DateTimeInterface $dateCreated): self
    {
        $this->date_created = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastUpdated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->last_updated;
    }

    public function setLastUpdated(?\DateTimeInterface $last_updated): self
    {
        $this->last_updated = $last_updated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPatientId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->patient_id;
    }

    public function setPatientId(int $patient_id): self
    {
        $this->patient_id = $patient_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentType(): ?int
    {
        return $this->payment_type;
    }

    public function setPaymentType(int $payment_type): self
    {
        $this->payment_type = $payment_type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsuranceName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->insurance_name;
    }

    public function setInsuranceName(?string $insurance_name): self
    {
        $this->insurance_name = $insurance_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsuranceNo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->insurance_no;
    }

    public function setInsuranceNo(?string $insurance_no): self
    {
        $this->insurance_no = $insurance_no;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCash() : float
    {
        return $this->cash;
    }

    public function setCash(float $cash): self
    {
        $this->cash = $cash;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttachmentId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->attachment_id;
    }

    public function setAttachmentId(int $attachment_id): self
    {
        $this->attachment_id = $attachment_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrimaryClientId(): int
    {
        return $this->primaryClientId;
    }

    public function setPrimaryClientId(int $client): self
    {
        $this->primaryClientId = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSecondaryClients() : ?PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->secondaryClients;
    }

    public function setSecondaryClients(?array $clients): self
    {
        $this->secondaryClients = $clients;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmployees() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }

    public function setEmployees(array $employees): self
    {
        $this->employees = $employees;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDates() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

    public function addDate(\DateTime $date): self
    {
        $orderDate = new OrderDates();
        $orderDate->setDate($date);
        $orderDate->setOrder($this);
        $this->dates[] = $orderDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDates(array $dates): self
    {
        foreach($dates as $date)
        {
            $this->addDate(new \DateTime($date));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes() : ?string
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    public function setNotes(?string $notes): self
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus() : int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(int $status): self
    {
        $this->notes = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupSequence()
    {
        $group = null;
        switch($this->payment_type) {
            case self::TYPE_InsuranceOnly:
                $group = 'insuranceOnly';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_InsuranceAndCash:
                $group = 'insuranceAndCash';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_CashOnly:
                $group = 'cashOnly';
                break;
        }

        return [
            [
                'Orders',
                $group
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

I decided to just run the SQL statement output by the persist against the DB and it seems not only was the patient missing but also the primary_client_id field.  I now assume it has something to do with the associations I have in there for patients and primaryclient since those are the two fields that are missing. I'm not sure what would be wrong there though.

Comment: Ok. Made that change but the issue still remains

Comment: Forget about it I didn't think you could but you can indeed, my bad

Comment: Be sure your column name in your database is patient_id. If not you can change the name of the attribute in the Orders entity class or add the name of the column in the Doctrine metadata above the $patient_id attribute.

Comment: yes, I tried mapping the field name as well just to be sure but the issue still remains

Comment: Forget about the first comment I added, your issue is you have an attribute $patients in the Orders entity class that has the same name of the attribute $patiend_id, you should change one of those in order to be different, in that way Doctrine is going to know how to map an entity attribute with a table column in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  One is named patients and the other is named patient_id, how are they named the same?  Also the $patient_id has the @ORM\Column whereas $patients does not so I thought that would make the latter know it's not a column?

Comment: Why do you even use JoinColumn? I only use it for ManyToMany relationships. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: I  use the join column cause I only want to save the id of the patient in this table, but I later want to do $orders->getPatients() to get the actual patient record

Comment: It seems like a conflict issue. Why you have a patient_id and primary_client_id since you have already set the appropriate associations (ManyToOne $patients and ManyToOne $primaryClient)?

Comment: That is the default behavior of symfony.

Comment: @ElementZero I think you need to read the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#saving-related-entities

Comment: @iiirxs maybe I'm missing something.  I use the field $patient_id to store the id for the Patient, then use $order->getPatients() to get the actual patient record later.  You are saying I should combine the field into one?  I guess I'm not sure how the set would work

Comment: You should completely remove the $patient_id field

Comment: If I do that how would I set the patients field though?  Cause right now I have no set on that and I assume it would take a patients class, not an int?

Comment: Exactly you would use a function addPatient(Patient $patient) to implement this functionality

Comment: Ok I see now. I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the associations work and how they save information.  I thought it would only save information to the database if there was an @ORM\Column.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of posterity, after the discussion in the post comments this is the end result of my entity.  It now saves the id's in the table, there was no need for a separate field JUST to save the int.  The only big difference is I need to lookup the patient and primary Client to pass in, instead of just passing the id value (integer).

**Code:**

```
$patient = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Patients::class)
    ->find($order->getPatientId());

$primaryClient = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Clients::class)
    ->findOneById($order->getPrimaryClient());

$db_order = new Orders();

$db_order->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
$db_order->setLastUpdated(null);
$db_order->setDateAssigned(null);
$db_order->setCreatedBy($user->getId());

$db_order->setAttachmentId($order->getFaxId());
$db_order->setPatient($patient);
$db_order->setPaymentType($order->getPaymentType());
$db_order->setInsuranceName($order->getInsuranceName());
$db_order->setInsuranceNo($order->getInsuranceNo());
$db_order->setCash($order->getCash());
$db_order->setPrimaryClient($primaryClient);
$db_order->setSecondaryClients($secondaryClients);
$db_order->setEmployees($employees);
$db_order->setDates($dates);
$db_order->setNotes($note);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($db_order);
$entityManager->flush();
```

**Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\GroupSequenceProviderInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrdersRepository")
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider()
 */
class Orders implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface
{
    const TYPE_InsuranceOnly = 1;
    const TYPE_InsuranceAndCash = 2;
    const TYPE_CashOnly = 3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date_created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $last_updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_assigned;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $created_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Attachments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $attachment_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","cashOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance And Collect or Cash Only then Cash field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $payment_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","insuranceOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance Only or Insurance And Collect then Insurance Name field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $insurance_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","insuranceOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance Only or Insurance And Collect then Insurance # field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $insurance_no;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=15, scale=2, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups = {"insuranceAndCash","cashOnly"}, message="If Payment Type is set to Insurance And Collect or Cash Only then Cash field cannot be blank")
     */
    private $cash;

    /**
     * One Order has Many Secondary Clients.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Clients")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="orders_secondary_clients",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $secondaryClients;

    /**
     * One Order has Many Employees.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="orders_employees",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      )
     */
    private $employees;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDates", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $dates;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=100000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $status = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Patients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $patient;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="primary_client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $primaryClient;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateAssigned(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_assigned;
    }

    public function setDateAssigned(?\DateTimeInterface $date_assigned): self
    {
        $this->date_assigned = $date_assigned;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy(): ?int
    {
        return $this->created_by;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy(int $created_by): self
    {
        $this->created_by = $created_by;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_created;
    }

    public function setDateCreated(\DateTimeInterface $dateCreated): self
    {
        $this->date_created = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastUpdated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->last_updated;
    }

    public function setLastUpdated(?\DateTimeInterface $last_updated): self
    {
        $this->last_updated = $last_updated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentType(): ?int
    {
        return $this->payment_type;
    }

    public function setPaymentType(int $payment_type): self
    {
        $this->payment_type = $payment_type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsuranceName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->insurance_name;
    }

    public function setInsuranceName(?string $insurance_name): self
    {
        $this->insurance_name = $insurance_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsuranceNo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->insurance_no;
    }

    public function setInsuranceNo(?string $insurance_no): self
    {
        $this->insurance_no = $insurance_no;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCash() : float
    {
        return $this->cash;
    }

    public function setCash(float $cash): self
    {
        $this->cash = $cash;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttachmentId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->attachment_id;
    }

    public function setAttachmentId(int $attachment_id): self
    {
        $this->attachment_id = $attachment_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSecondaryClients() : ?PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->secondaryClients;
    }

    public function setSecondaryClients(?array $clients): self
    {
        $this->secondaryClients = $clients;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmployees() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }

    public function setEmployees(array $employees): self
    {
        $this->employees = $employees;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDates() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

    public function addDate(\DateTime $date): self
    {
        $orderDate = new OrderDates();
        $orderDate->setDate($date);
        $orderDate->setOrder($this);
        $this->dates[] = $orderDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDates(array $dates): self
    {
        foreach($dates as $date)
        {
            $this->addDate(new \DateTime($date));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotes() : ?string
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    public function setNotes(?string $notes): self
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus() : int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(int $status): self
    {
        $this->notes = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupSequence()
    {
        $group = null;
        switch($this->payment_type) {
            case self::TYPE_InsuranceOnly:
                $group = 'insuranceOnly';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_InsuranceAndCash:
                $group = 'insuranceAndCash';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_CashOnly:
                $group = 'cashOnly';
                break;
        }

        return [
            [
                'Orders',
                $group
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getPatient(): Patients
    {
        return $this->patient;
    }

    public function setPatient(Patients $patient) : self
    {
        $this->patient = $patient;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrimaryClient(): Clients
    {
        return $this->primaryClient;
    }

    pu]
```